# How to write unions of generic intervals as unions of disjoint generic intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let us call $\mathscr{I}^1$ the set of *all* intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, including: the empty set, one-point sets $\{x\}$, open intervals $(a,b)$, closed intervals $[a,b]$, half-open intervals $(a,b], [a,b)$, open rays $(a,+\infty), (-\infty,a)$ and closed rays $[a,+\infty), (-\infty,a]$. Similarly, for a fixed integer $n \geq 1$ we can define the set $\mathscr{I}^n = \{ J = I_1 \times \ldots \times I_n : I_j \in \mathscr{I}^1 \}$ of all intervals in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider now the set $\mathscr{U}^n$ of all finite unions of intervals, that is $\mathscr{U}^n = \{ J_1 \cup \ldots \cup J_k : J_j \in \mathscr{I}^n \}$.

My question is: how do I come to prove that every element of $\mathscr{U}^n$ can be written as a finite union of *disjoint* intervals, that is $\mathscr{U}^n = \{ J_1 \cup \ldots \cup J_k : J_j \in \mathscr{I}^n, \, J_i \cap J_j = \emptyset \text{ for } i \neq j \}$? On StackExchange I only found discussions on particular cases of this question, while I am searching for a comprehensive approach of the problem.

My attempt: So far I managed to prove that
$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^k J_j = \bigcup_{j=1}^k \left( J_j - \bigcup_{i=j+1}^k J_i \right) \, ,
$$
which gives me the union $J_1 \cup \ldots \cup J_k$ as a finite union of disjoint sets, but these sets need not be elements of $\mathscr{I}^n$. Any hint on how to proceed would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer for the one-dimensional case.

Let the endpoints of each interval $J_i$ be $a_i$ and $b_i$, where $a_i$ and $b_i$ may be either real numbers or $\pm \infty$.  Now let $x_1, \dotsc, x_K$ be the elements of $\{a_1, b_1, \dotsc, a_k, b_k\}$ arranged in increasing order.  Then each interval $J_i$ is a union of elements of the pairwise disjoint set of intervals
\begin{equation}
    \{\{x_1\}, (x_1, x_2), \{x_2\}, \dotsc, (x_{K - 1}, x_K), \{x_K\}\}
  \setminus
    \{\{-\infty\}, \{+\infty\}\},
\end{equation} so $\bigcup_i J_i$ is also a union of disjoint intervals.

Extension to the multi-dimensional case is tiresome but obvious.